# need help regarding amazon sample project

Tags: ios, sdk, amazon-web-services

hi all i have download the amazon sample project from 
[here](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ios)

i have successfully build the project and have entered the required credentials but upon tapping any of the two buttons the app. crashes with the following crash log

```
2010-12-31 13:46:30.313 AWSiosDEMO[5432/0x3e7c27c8] [lvl=1] (no func) In SignURLRequest: String to Sign = [GET

Fri, 31 Dec 2010 13:46:29 GMT+05:00
/]
2010-12-31 13:46:30.315 AWSiosDEMO[5432/0x3e7c27c8] [lvl=1] (no func) Request headers:
2010-12-31 13:46:30.315 AWSiosDEMO[5432/0x3e7c27c8] [lvl=1] (no func) User-Agent: aws-sdk-iOS/0.1.0 iPhone-OS/4.0.1 en_PK
2010-12-31 13:46:30.316 AWSiosDEMO[5432/0x3e7c27c8] [lvl=1] (no func) Host: s3.amazonaws.com
2010-12-31 13:46:30.316 AWSiosDEMO[5432/0x3e7c27c8] [lvl=1] (no func) Authorization: AWS AKIAJ5JUKPHXGS4HOWOA:ykO5gbyEyymFCZIpmHZDAYEuscI=
2010-12-31 13:46:30.316 AWSiosDEMO[5432/0x3e7c27c8] [lvl=1] (no func) Content-Length: 0
2010-12-31 13:46:30.317 AWSiosDEMO[5432/0x3e7c27c8] [lvl=1] (no func) Date: Fri, 31 Dec 2010 13:46:29 GMT+05:00
2010-12-31 13:46:31.667 AWSiosDEMO[5432:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘AmazonServiceException’, reason: ‘(null)’
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x3037cfd3 __exceptionPreprocess + 114
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x321308a5 objc_exception_throw + 24
2 AWSiosDEMO 0x0000a04b -[AmazonS3Client invoke:] + 826
3 AWSiosDEMO 0x00009a9b -[AmazonS3Client listBuckets:] + 14
4 AWSiosDEMO 0x00009ad5 -[AmazonS3Client listBuckets] + 52
5 AWSiosDEMO 0x00002bdb -[AWSiosDEMOViewController listBuckets:] + 158
6 CoreFoundation 0x303077ad -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 24
7 UIKit 0×32383829 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 84
8 UIKit 0x323837c9 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 32
9 UIKit 0x3238379b -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38
10 UIKit 0x323834ed -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 356
11 UIKit 0x32383b3b -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 342
12 UIKit 0x323824ed -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 368
13 UIKit 0x32381e67 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 262
14 UIKit 0x3237db5b -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 298
15 UIKit 0x3237d507 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5022
16 GraphicsServices 0x31a78147 PurpleEventCallback + 666
17 CoreFoundation 0x30352aab __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
18 CoreFoundation 0x3035484f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
19 CoreFoundation 0x3035562d __CFRunLoopRun + 520
20 CoreFoundation 0x302fe8eb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
21 CoreFoundation 0x302fe7f3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
22 GraphicsServices 0x31a776ef GSEventRunModal + 114
23 GraphicsServices 0x31a7779b GSEventRun + 62
24 UIKit 0x323272a7 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
25 UIKit 0x32325e17 UIApplicationMain + 670
26 AWSiosDEMO 0x0000293b main + 70
27 AWSiosDEMO 0x000028f0 start + 40
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of ‘AmazonServiceException’
```

I need help why this error occurs where i am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This caused me quite a bit of grief as well.

The problem is not having any domains setup in SimpleDB.  If you follow [Amazon's SimpleDB Getting Started Guide](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/SDB/latest/sdb-gsg.pdf) and create a domain and some attributes in the [Scratchpad app](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1137?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1), you'll be able to click the `Simple DB - List Domains` button without a crash.

I would assume the `S3 - List Buckets` button is a similar issue.